# Multiple Populate in mongoose not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the schema like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const deepPopulate = require('mongoose-deep-populate')(mongoose);
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const AcceptedMessageSchema = new Schema({
  body: String,
  seen: Boolean,
  sender: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User"
  }],
  recipient: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User"
  }]
}, { timestamps: { createdAt: 'created_at' } });

AcceptedMessageSchema.plugin(deepPopulate);
module.exports = mongoose.model('Accepted', AcceptedMessageSchema);
```

When I accept a message/mail from other user, I save it into `acceptedMessageSchema` so when the other user logs in, he can see that I have accepted his message.

Similary, I want to track how many messages I have accepted so I tried this:

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const checkJWT = require('../../middlewares/check-jwt');
const AcceptedMessageSchema = require('../../models/mailbox/accepted-messages');

router.get('/getAcceptedMessages', checkJWT, (req, res, next) => {
  AcceptedMessageSchema.find({ recipient: req.decoded.user._id, }, { sender: req.decoded.user._id }).populate('recipient').populate('sender').lean().exec(function (err, messages) {
    console.log('getAcceptedMessages ', messages);
    res.json({
      success: true,
      messages: messages,
      message: "Successful"
    });
  });
});

router.post('/acceptMessage', checkJWT, (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('accept');
  const accept = new AcceptedMessageSchema();
  accept.body = req.decoded.user.name + ' has accepted your message';
  accept.recipient = req.decoded.user._id;
  accept.sender = req.body.id;
  AcceptedMessageSchema.find({ sender: req.body.id }).lean().exec(function (err, senders) {
    const messageFound = senders.some((obj) => {
      return JSON.stringify(obj.recipient) === JSON.stringify(req.decoded.user['_id']);
    });
    if (!messageFound) {
      accept.save().then(messageSaved => {
        res.json({
          success: true,
          message: "Accepted!"
        });
      }).catch(error => {
        next(error);
        res.json({
          success: false,
          message: "Couldn't send message"
        });
      });
    } else {
      res.json({
        success: false,
        message: 'Message already accepted!'
      });
    }
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

but it returns an empty array.

Data in db:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5d6fd251263b282ac0f7860d"
    },
    "updatedAt": {
        "$date": "2019-09-04T15:03:45.842Z"
    },
    "created_at": {
        "$date": "2019-09-04T15:03:45.842Z"
    },
    "sender": {
        "$oid": "5d6b06eca4b60b09b3c376e1"
    },
    "recipient": {
        "$oid": "5d6b0718a4b60b09b3c376e2"
    },
    "body": "John has accepted your message",
    "__v": 0
}
```

so here sender `5d6b06eca4b60b09b3c376e1` has sent message to recipient `5d6b0718a4b60b09b3c376e2`

Comment: What happens when you execute the find query in mongodb terminal, do you receive the records? If yes then you can try converting the request to ObjectId in your find query. I am not sure if it is going to help you but worth trying.

Answer (score 0):

The second parameters of [Model.find()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) is projection so looks like your query `AcceptedMessageSchema.find({ recipient: req.decoded.user._id, }, { sender: req.decoded.user._id })` is wrong. It should be:

```
AcceptedMessageSchema.find({ recipient: req.decoded.user._id, sender: req.decoded.user._id })...
```